# Pesquisa no localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Bom estou precisando fazer uma pesquisa no localStorage, e nisto preciso saber quais item começão com um determinado caractere, por exemplo:

```
Quero pegar todos as key que começão com pes_ ou seja no exemplo abaixo eu pegaria.
---- KEY ----------|------ VALUE ------
pes_918239812938   | {OBJ 1}
pes_123123121214   | {obj 2}
cel_13             | {obj 3}

No caso acima ele teria que mostras pes_918239812938, pes_123123121214
```

Eu ja consegui fazer a pesquisa utilizando um foreach porém passando o que eu quero em si, minha ideia é montar uma função que se eu passa-se para ela pes_ como no exemplo ele me retorna-se todos e se caso eu envia-se pes_918239812938, ele me retornava o próprio.

```
function fnc_PesquisaBD(key){
  var output = "";
  for (key in localStorage){  
      output += key + "\n" ; 
      output += localStorage [ key ]+ "\n" ; 
      output +=  "\n" ; 
  }
  return output;
}
```

Como devo fazer isto ?

A RESPOSTA INFORMADA PELO NOSSO AMIGO @SERGIO NÃO SATISFAZ TODA DUVIDA DE MINHA PERGUNTA. O PROBLEMA É QUANDO TENHO QUE PEGAR VARIAS TUPLAS.

```
var pessoasCelulas = getData("pescel_");
pessoasCelulas = pessoasCelulas[0];

console.log(pessoasCelulas);
for(var i = 0; i < pessoasCelulas.length; i++){
    if(pessoasCelulas[i].COD_IDENT_CELUL == w_codigo_celula){
        var pessoa = getData("pes_" +pessoasCelulas[i].COD_IDENT_PESSO);
            pessoa = pessoa[0];
        w_elemento = [pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO, pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO, pessoasCelulas[i].FLG_IDENT_PESSO, pessoa.FLG_STATU_PESSO, pessoasCelulas[i].FLG_STATU_PARTC];
        arrayConfig.push(w_elemento);
        console.log(arrayConfig);
    }

}
```

ESTE CÓDIGO UTILIZO PARA PESQUISAR TODAS AS PESSOAS DE UMA DETERMINADA CÉLULA, PORÉM ELE ESTA ME RETORNANDO O SEGUINTE NO CONSOLE.

[image: RETORNO NO CONSOLE LOG]

DE ACORDO COM O QUE ESTA EM MEU LOCALSTORAGE DEVERIA VOLTAR 3 REGISTRO.

[image: LOCALSTORAGE]

O CÓDIGO QUE ESTOU UTILIZANDO PARA PESQUISAR NO LOCALSTORAGE É ESTE:

```
function getData(chave) {
   return Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
      return key.indexOf(chave) == 0;
   }).map(function(key) {
      return JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
 });
}
```

PARA "SOLUCIONAR" O PROBLEMA ASCIMA PRECISEI FAZER MUITA MANOBRA DEVIDO AO CÓDIGO ESTÁ RETORNANDO ARRAY DENTRO DE ARRAY:

```
    var pessoasCelulas = getData("pescel_");
for(var i = 0; i < pessoasCelulas.length; i++){
    if(pessoasCelulas[i][0].COD_IDENT_CELUL == w_codigo_celula){
        var pessoa = getData("pes_" +pessoasCelulas[i][0].COD_IDENT_PESSO);
            pessoa = pessoa[0][0];
        w_elemento = [pessoa.TXT_NOMEX_PESSO, pessoa.COD_IDENT_PESSO, pessoasCelulas[i][0].FLG_IDENT_PESSO, pessoa.FLG_STATU_PESSO, pessoasCelulas[i][0].FLG_STATU_PARTC];
        arrayConfig.push(w_elemento);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes fazer uma função que procura chaves dependendo do argumento que lhe passas. Algo assim:

```
localStorage.pes_54321 = '{"baz":"biz"}';
localStorage.pes_12345 = '{"foo":"bar"}';

function getData(chave) {
    return Object.keys(localStorage).filter(function(key) {
        return key.indexOf(chave) == 0;
    }).map(function(key) {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage[key]);
    });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(getData('pes'))); // [{"foo":"bar"},{"baz":"biz"}]
console.log(JSON.stringify(getData('pes_54321'))); // [{"baz":"biz"}]
```

Essa função retorna todas as chaves que começam com a string que passares à função. O retorno é uma array, depois podes usar como precisares.

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ayw7zky4/

Comment: E se caso eu passar um nome todo, ele me retorna apenas ele ?

Comment: @RenanRodrigues exato, uma array com apenas um elemento. Juntei um exemplo.

Comment: O seu código está retornando um array dentro do outro array, ai esta ficando assim array[0]{ array[0] { object, object, ...} } Como mudar isto ??

Comment: @RenanRodrigues o meu código gera objetos dentro de array, não array dentro de array com objetos dentro. Dá uma olhada na consola do meu jsFiddle. Será que estás a integrar em outro código que está a criar esse problema?

Comment: Eu estou setando inicialmente como "[]" será que é por isto ?

Comment: Outra coisa, seu código está retornando apenas um, por exemplo se pesquisa tudo pes_ ele so volta o primeiro.

Comment: Como fazer para retorna todos ?

Comment: ATUALIZEI MINHA PERGUNTA

Comment: @RenanRodrigues como coloquei na resposta o meu código retorna multiplos caso a string seja comum, como no exemplo `getData('pes')`. Vou re-ler a tua pergunta agora com as modificações.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues acho que estás a complicar, diz quando estiveres por aí e posso ajudar-te no chat.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39763/discussion-between-sergio-and-renan-rodrigues).